# Git Integration plugin absent from Datagrip?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

There is something I don't understand... I can't find the "Git integration" plugin anywhere in DataGrip 2016.3.3 (JetBrains IDE). PyCharm is installed on the same machine and it has the Git Integration plugin. I also have DataGrip installed on another machine with the plugin.

But on this machine right now, no Git Integration... It's not even in the plugins repositories.

I tried uninstalling, re-installing, updating but no luck.

Here is a extract from the idea.log

```
2017-02-22 07:49:09,886 [   6403]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - P:/CARTO/Outils_carto/git/zppnmo/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
2017-02-22 07:49:09,886 [   6403]   WARN - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Project files cannot be watched (are they under network mount?) 
2017-02-22 07:49:09,886 [   6403]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - Error: activating non existing vcs: Git 
2017-02-22 07:49:09,886 [   6403]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - unwatched roots: [P:/CARTO/Outils_carto/git/zppnmo]
```

And a screenshot of the plugin menu
[image: Plugin menu]

What am I missing??

Comment: Are on EAP or release version?

Comment: Release version (2016.3.3)

Comment: 1) Please share your `idea.log` (`Help | Show Log in xxx`) 2) Are you sure that it's not listed in `Settings/Preferences | Plugins`? It's standard bundled plugin .. so comes with IDE by default.

Comment: Gob, thank you for the report — we've found that we occasionally deleted the plugin for 2016.3.3. We uploaded it again. I posted the general answer for the following readers. Please, check.

Comment: BTW here is a tutorial about Git in DataGrip https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/06/01/tutorial-how-to-use-git-with-datagrip/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Settings → Plugins → Browse repositories** → search for the plugin you need.

[image]

Comment: I tried searching for the plugin and I didn't find it first. It seemed absent from the repositories... I upgraded DataGrip and then I saw your post, so I tried searching for it again. It's there and it is now installed. I still don't understand why though...  Thank you!

Comment: I described it in the previous comment.

Comment: So, there are two tutorials that can help:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/12/11/datagrip-and-github-step-by-step-integration/
https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/06/01/tutorial-how-to-use-git-with-datagrip/

Answer (score 1):

Starting from DataGrip 2020.2 GitHub and Git plugins are bundled.

[image]