# How do I enable Version Control in DataGrip 2016.3.4 on Mac?

Tags: mysql, database, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I am running JetBrains DataGrip on Mac and I cannot figure out how to enable version control. View | Tool Windows | Version Control is greyed out and there is nothing about VC in the preferences window.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the answer on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42393468/3001845

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Integration plugin absent from Datagrip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42357392/git-integration-plugin-absent-from-datagrip)